# Extending package controller

Tags: controller, laravel-4, package

I'm developing a Laravel package, which uses some MainController and AuthController. Both of them extends MyBaseController (also in the package). This is the directory structure for controllers:

```
workbench/developer/package/src/controllers/MyBaseController.php
workbench/developer/package/src/controllers/MainController.php
workbench/developer/package/src/controllers/AuthController.php
```

All of the controllers have defined namespace:

```
namespace Developer\Package;
```

The problem is that I'm getting this error:

```
Class 'Developer\Package\MyBaseController' not found
```

Could anybody tell me, what I'm doing wrong or how to fix this?

Comment: did you do a '''composer dumpautoload -o''' in the main app? also would be interesting to see your autoload entries in composer.json of the package.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your base controller is in your base composer.json and run

```
composer du
```

in the root of your laravel Application